# An integral for which I don't trust WolframAlpha

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20e%5E(-(t-i)%5E4)%20dt%20for%20t%3D-inf%20to%20inf) tells me that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t = 0.$$ I am suspicious of this, because of the idea that for nice enough $f$, since $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t-a) \, \mathrm{d}t$$ is holomorphic in $a$ and takes the same value for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it should be independent of $a$ by the identity principle; and then $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^4} \, \mathrm{d}t = 2 \cdot \Gamma(5/4).$$ But WolframAlpha even tells me numerically that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is close to $0$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe you are correct. Without having done the work, I think a large rectangle contour will confirm your intuition.

Comment: The integrals are equal provided that $i$ is a real number, but it isn't.

Comment: @WW1 $i$ is the usual $i = \sqrt{-1}.$ Why doesn't the argument here work?

Comment: Because $i$ is not on the contour of integration for your integral

Comment: @WW1 That shouldn't matter by the identity principle, or as User8128 suggests (essentially) the contour of integration can be shifted in the $y$ direction without changing the integral, since it only matters that it connects $\mathrm{Re}[z] = -\infty$ and $\mathrm{Re}[z] = \infty.$ I am pretty confident in either argument but I thought I would ask here just to double check. (I usually trust wolframalpha blindly so it is irritating when something strange like this turns up)

Comment: @WW1: The argument for $a=i$ isn't about making a change of variable: it's about analytic continuation.

Comment: For the fun type $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(t-\color{red}{1.0}i)^4} \,dt  $ and you will get the value !!!

Comment: Also if you ask to integrate the real part. I suspect what's happening here is that wolfram or mathematica decides that, because it was given given symbolic complex input, that `inf` was meant to be `ComplexInfinity`.

Comment: @Hurkyl. Could you check with Mathematica ? I am just curious.

Comment: They seem to have already corrected this.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(t-\color{red}{1}i)^4} \,dt$ works

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just as User8128 commented, I believe that you are perfectly correct.

Without changing variable and using another CAS
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t=\color{red}{-\frac{(t-i)\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4},(t-i)^4\right)}{4 \sqrt[4]{(t-i)^4}}}=-\frac{1}{4} (t-i) E_{\frac{3}{4}}\left((t-i)^4\right)$$ 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t=i \left(E_{\frac{3}{4}}(-4)-\Re\left(E_{\frac{3}{4}}(-4)\right)\right)$$ $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t=\frac{(-1)^{1/4}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4},-4\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-i
   \Re\left(-\frac{(-1)^{3/4}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4},-4\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=2\, \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) $$  Notice that, for the indefinite integral, Wolfram Alpha correctly reports the expression written in red.

What is interesting is that, if you ask Wolfram Alpha
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t=-\frac i4E_{\frac{3}{4}}(-1)$$
$$\int^{0}_{-\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(t-i)^4} \, \mathrm{d}t=+\frac i4E_{\frac{3}{4}}(-1)$$ leading to the $0$ you obtained.

There is obviously a bug that I suggest you to report.

Comment: The bug is kind of interesting. Just below i it still works, e.g. for 0.99 i [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-(t-0.99*I)**4%5D,%7Bt,-Infinity,Infinity%7D%5D) at 1 i it fails.

Comment: @Jannick. Type $1.0i$ and it works !!!

Comment: Yes true, that is really funny. For integer one it already fails but for float one it still works. For 1.01 it fails however.

Comment: @Jannick.**Funny** may not be the most appropriate term here ! Cheers and thanks for your previous comment which made me trying $1.0i$.

Comment: It works with `1.0i` because the number is then machine number and is treated with a bit different logic than if it's exact `10/10 i`.

Comment: At the risk of sounding passive-aggressive, my experience shows that Wolfram doesn't treat bug reports very seriously. So reporting might be fruitless, though the proper thing to do anyway. On a more constructive note, the bug in question does not appear in Mathematica - NIntegrate[Exp[-(t - I)^4], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] returns 1.8128 as expected (and Integrate gives an expression equivalent to $2\Gamma(5/4)$). This might help narrow down the source of this bug.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: The original bug does, at the least in Mathematica 9. `Integrate[Exp[-(t - I)^4],  {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` yields 0. NIntegrate with the same argument returns 1.8128 + very little i, just like what you see.

Comment: @kkm In Mathematica 11.1 the bug seems solved: `Integrate[Exp[-(t - I)^4], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}] // FullSimplify` yields `I (ExpIntegralE[3/4, -4] - Re[ExpIntegralE[3/4, -4]])`.

Comment: Yep, I'm using 11.1, where Integrate gives a correct result.

Comment: With version $\texttt{10.0.0.0}$: $\color{#f00}{\texttt{N}}\texttt{Integrate} \implies 1.8128 - 5.68434 \times 10^{-14}\,\mathrm{i}$ while  $\color{#f00}{\texttt{I}}\texttt{ntegrate} \implies 0$. If we write $\left(\,t - \color{#f00}{1.0}\,\mathrm{i}\,\right)$ (with $\color{#f00}{\mathrm{I}}\texttt{ntegrate}$), the result is $0.906402 + 0.906402\,\mathrm{i}$ !!!!!!!!.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, I did submit a bug report and referenced this question and the answers. We'll see what happens!

Answer (score 14):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{t - \ic}^{4}}\dd t & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\expo{-\pars{t - \ic}^{4}} +
\expo{-\pars{-t - \ic}^{4}}}\dd t =
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{t + \ic}^{4}}\dd t =
2\,\Re\int_{\ic}^{\infty + \ic}\expo{-t^{4}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-2\,\lim_{R \to \infty}\Re\int_{1}^{0}\expo{-\pars{R + \ic y}^{4}}\ic\,\dd y -
2\,\Re\int_{\infty}^{0}\expo{-t^{4}}\dd t -
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-\pars{\ic y}^{4}}\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
-2\,\lim_{R \to \infty}\Im\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-\pars{R + \ic y}^{4}}\,\dd y +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-3/4}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-2\,\lim_{R \to \infty}\Im\int_{0}^{1}\exp\pars{-R^{4} - 4R^{3}y\ic + 6R^{2}y^{2} + 4Ry^{3}\ic - y^{4}}\,\dd y +
{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{1 \over 4}
\\[1cm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{1 \over 4}
\\[2mm] & -
2\lim_{R \to \infty}\braces{%
\expo{-R^{4}}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\pars{y^{2}\bracks{6R^{2} - y^{2}}}
\sin\pars{4Ry\bracks{y^{2} - R^{2}}}\,\dd y}
\end{align}

> - $\ds{y^{2}\pars{6R^{2} - y^{2}}}$ has a maximum at $\ds{y_{m} = \root{3}R}$.
>     $\ds{y_{m} > 1}$ when $\ds{R > {\root{3} \over 3}}$.
> - It vanishes at $\ds{y = 0}$ and at $\ds{y = \root{6}R}$.
> - It $\ds{\to -\infty}$ when $\ds{y \to \infty}$.
> - It's clear that $\ds{0 < y^{2}\pars{6R^{2} - y^{2}} < 6R^{2} - 1}$ when $\ds{y \in \pars{0,1}}$ with $\ds{R > {\root{3} \over 3}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
0 & < \verts{\expo{-R^{4}}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\pars{y^{2}\bracks{6R^{2} - y^{2}}}
\sin\pars{4Ry\bracks{y^{2} - R^{2}}}\,\dd y}_{\ R\ >\ \!\root{3}/3}
\\[5mm] & <
\expo{-R^{4}}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\pars{1^{2}\bracks{6R^{2} - 1^{2}}}\,\dd y =
\exp\pars{-R^{4} + 6R^{2} - 1}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\color{#f00}{\large 0}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mbox{such that}\quad
\bbx{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{t - \ic}^{4}}\dd t =
{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{1 \over 4}} \approx 1.8128
\end{align}